# How to send debug log with email

Tags: exception, debug-logs

Assume that We have try catch structure and if exception throw, I want to send all debug log in email as an attachment.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, this wouldn't be possible. There's no way to know what the ID of the Apex Log for the current transaction, and further, it wouldn't be available until after you tried to send the email. In addition, logging would have to be enabled to begin with, which most likely requires an API callout to enable, and it also wouldn't affect the current transaction. You can capture the Stack Trace, and of course, the error message, but that's about all you can do.